# WebpackCopyPlugin not copying files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, webpack, yarnpkg

I have created a Chrome extension, I need to copy the manifest file from the root of the project to the dist folder when building with webpack.

I have the WebpackCopyPlugin.

When running `npm build` I get no debug information as I should from the `debug:"debug"` option and the file is also not copied.

The simplified directory structure is like this:

```
/
 manifest.json
 /dist
```

I want:

```
/
 manifest.json
 /dist
    manifest.json
```

In my webpack.config.js I have this inside my build configuration:

```
build:
    plugins: [
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
          {
              from:"manifest.json",
              to:"dist",
              toType:"file",
              force: true,
          }
      ],
          {
              debug:'debug',
              copyUnmodified: true
          }
      )
  ],
```

Comment: create a reproducible repository and open as an issue into the plugin github repo.